# Using LINQ EF query to get all dates that fall in given months

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using .Net MVC with EF for a simple web service with web API. In my model I have a date field called "Created". How do I write a query to find all entries where month of "Created" date is part of a given month list (List)?

e.g. my month list is (1,4,5)
I need to find all entries where createdDate.Month is part of the above list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Contains` method on your desired months list:

```
List<int> months = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5 };

var items = context.Table.Where(i => month.Contains(i.Created.Month)).ToList();
```

Comment: Would this optimize the SQL query or just iterate all rows checking for the condition?

Comment: `IN` statement will be generated within SQL query.

Comment: then LINQ-EF is a bit smarter than I thought! +1

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Also good to know it generates IN statement.